# AutoFiltering two separate block of data in different rows

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

In a worksheet I'm working on a the moment there are two sections that need to be filtered to show when data is in the cells.

The first section has data in column B and is working fine using the code

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$48:$D$507")
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
End With
```

The next handful of rows have data sitting in column A, but applying the same code as above doesn't seem to include the rows that have data in them.  The code I've used is

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$508:$D$537")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
End With
```

What needs to be changed or added to get the second block of data showing?

Comment: Don't think you're allowed >1 Autofilter on a sheet.

Comment: Cannot be done. Will you be only looking at the filtered data or will you be copying? Do you have data to the right of column `D`? If not, you could hide entire rows for the remaining *handful* of data, or for all of the data.

Comment: You mean to filter the range $A$48:$D$507 if column A or column B is not empty and the rest of the range $A$508:$D$537 only if column A is not empty. This is done using an auxiliary column and two formulas: one for the first and one for the second range. In this case have to filter the auxiliary column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another user commented, you cannot have autofilters on multiple ranges on one sheet (try doing it manually without VBA - if you try to apply a 2nd filter it will remove the 1st one).

However you can have autofilters on multiple tables on one sheet. Convert your ranges to tables first, then filter the tables like below:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
```